# How do I print the '%' character with 'printf'?

Tags: perl, printf

Simple problem that I can't figure out...

How can I print a '%' character within a `printf` string? The code below prints it, but gives an 'invalid conversion' error as well.

```
printf "\t\t".$hour."00 HRS\t=>\t%.2f\t%.2f\t%.1f\%\n", $total, $max15, ($max15/$total*100);
```

Should output something like:

```
        0000 HRS    =>    3125.19    898.02    28.7%
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You would use %%, not \% (from man [printf](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html))

Comment: Does "man printf" really tell you about the Perl function on your system? On mine, it only tells about the command-line program. I can get the C function with "man 3 printf"; if I want to read about the Perl function, I use "perldoc -f printf"

Comment: At least it looks like we all agree on the answer.

Comment: @Rob Kennedy: "perldoc -f printf" doesn't give me any detail but instead refers me to sprintf. "perldoc -f sprintf" indeed gives me all the details I need, much like "man printf". "man 3 printf" OTOH gives me the man page for an OCaml library. That's on a recent kUbuntu (with OCaml installed obviously!)

Answer (score 5):

Instead of \% use %% :)

Answer (score 5):

%%  for   a single %

Answer (score 3):

On hindsight, there was a crude alternative which would have done the same thing.

Print the '%' symbol as a string:

```
printf "\t\t".$hour."00 HRS\t=>\t%.2f\t%.2f\t%.1f%s\n", $total, $max15, ($max15/$total*100), "%";
```

Answer (score 2):

Use %% to print a single %

```
printf "\t\t".$hour."00 HRS\t=>\t%.2f\t%.2f\t%.1f%%\n", $total, $max15, ($max15/$total*100);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit tricky because the documentation for the template for [printf](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/printf.html) is actually in the documentation for [sprintf](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html). You have to catch that line in the middle of the paragraph to know to look there.